# Graphics Card Compatibility w/Gigabyte MB & Ryzen 5 CPU

Tags: graphics-card

I am building my unit from scratch and so far all I have is the MB, PS, CPU, and 64GB DDMR4.
When I power it up (no monitor or input) the CPU Cooling Fan does not come on - so I assume either the fan is broken or my scratch needs something else to start the fan. The 'experts' at the hardware store tell me all I need is a graphics card - then the fan will run.

So I found my perfect card: Gigabyte Radeon RX 6600 XT Eagle 8G Graphics Card, WINDFORCE 3X Cooling System, 8GB 128-bit GDDR6, GV-R66XTEAGLE-8GD Video Card. It (like the MB) is made by Gigabyte - but my specs say that the Ryzen 5 supports PCle 4.0 x16.

I need some really good 'gamer' expertise here. Does the RX 6600 XT Eagle comply with the PCle 4.0 x16 specification standard?

p.s. I have not got to the SSD or SATA drives yet.

Comment: I dont think this is really on topic here. Maybe https://superuser.com is more appropriate.  But your CPU cooler fan should still turn on without a graphics processor - unless it's temperature based, but usually the main CPU fan will always be spinning.

Comment: @Joachim, I disagree. A GPU may be used for gaming, but it may just as well be used for CAD, Machine Learning, cryptocurrency mining, etc. It is therefore *not* gaming specific.

Comment: I apologize, I thought a gamer was not only a person that played games - but someone who had an intimate knowledge of the hardware the games were using. I guess you all are less mechanics than you are drivers.  p.s. really great racecar drivers know their cars inside and out. Peace.

Comment: @DaveFashenpour, no need to apologize. You are new here, and are still getting used to how this site works. Consider taking the [tour](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tour) to gain a better understanding of what kind of questions you can or can't ask here. Keep in mind that even the best racecar drivers likely won't appreciate being asked about anything not directly relevant to their race during a pit stop.

Comment: Agreed. Thanks.

Comment: Best bet would likely be a reddit sub; there's at least one for PC part or build suggestions and feedback.

Comment: @DaveFashenpour it's not a question of whether the 'drivers' here also have knowledge of 'mechanics', but whether questions about purely 'mechanics' (that have nothing to do with driving) are *on-topic* on this Q&A board.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is off-topic here.

Comment: Case fans and CPU cooler should come on immediately. Something's not plugged in right or the BIOS is wrong. Haven't seen a MB w/o embedded video since... ever; it does not "need" a graphics card. "Gamers" haven't had to know how to edit a batch file to find the IRQ of a sound card for 30y now. - I wouldn't be trying to get it to post before I had a HD in it.

Comment: To determine if this question is on-topic, we need to assess its relevance and usefulness to gamers. Graphics cards and gaming go hand in hand; even though they have other applications, most people associate them with gaming, which is why OP posted this question on a gaming site. I think this makes the question relevant and useful for our community, and therefore on-topic.